# How many threads should git diff be using?

Tags: multithreading, git, docker, virtualbox

I am running git in a Docker container in a VirtualBox VM to which 2 CPU cores are assigned.

When running `git diff` I find that there is only a single `git` thread is running while my CPU load hovers at 50%. Is this normal? Should `git diff`not be running at least two threads? (Calculating diffs on multiple files should be parallelised, right?)

I already checked that my Docker container does actually see two CPU cores...

If this is a VM/Docker-related bug, is there a way of forcing two threads?

Comment: Git does not implement parallel-ized `diff`. Perhaps it should, at least for actual context diffs, although this would add quite a bit of complexity (the diff output is required to occur in a name-sorted order).

Comment: @torek Thanks for letting me know. I thought my sub-optimal configuration was causing bugs to surface.